# Why is the C++ standard library bundled with the compiler instead of the os?

Tags: c++, c

I am sorry if this is a naive question, but there's something I can't get my head around.

Why is the C++ standard library bundled with different compiler implementations (`g++`'s `libstdc++` and `clang`'s `libc++`) instead of coming bundled with a (UNIX-like) Operating System, just as, say the C standard library does? Why isn't it maintained alongside the C library, considering that it's a superset of it?

Comment: "Why isn't it maintained alongside the C library, considering that it's a superset of it"? : Well they are maintained side by side. what do you mean?

Comment: @40two Well that is ambiguous you are right. To clarify, I mean why aren't they maintained under the same umbrella, say for instance, under `glibc` or another C standard library project.

Comment: The compiler and library need to agree on the binary interface used for the library. C compilers (mostly) agree on a common calling convention and such, so it's pretty easy to maintain the library separate from the compiler. C++ compilers more often have differences in calling conventions and such, so the library needs to be compiled separately for each.

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that C++ is a different language with its own committee. Maintaining compatibility with C doesn't mean that they are the same language.

Comment: IIRC, in Windows, the OS has the libc library. And when it isn't sufficiently up-to-date, you need to install the redistributable packages.

Comment: It doesn't.  Covered by [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx).

Comment: Having an OS doesn't mean you need a C++ standard library. But having a C++ compiler almost certainly does.

Comment: @Mysticial: The libc library that ships with Windows is not intended to be used for applications.  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx

Comment: @NlightNFotis Also note that C++ is not a strict superset of C.

Comment: @NlightNFotis, As a library example, `gets` is gone in C11 and exists in C++11 (but is gone in C++14). `gets_s` is optional in C11 and non-existent in C++11.

Comment: In practice, both the C and C++ standard libraries are typically split into binaries and headers, and the former are distributed independently of the compiler in either case. Perhaps the real question is why the _header_ components of the C++ standard library are distributed with the compiler, but the same is not done with C. The answer is that C is an integral component of UNIX and C++ isn't; the C header components aren't distributed with the compiler because they're _already_ part of the base OS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The basic reason is that there is no standard C++ ABI -- every compiler tends to have its own ABI that is different from and incompatible with that of other compilers.  On the other hand, most OSes define a standard C ABI that they use and supply a standard C library for, and all C compilers for that OS support that ABI.

Comment: +1 for actually reading the question and answering the specific point it asks (why C++ has one library per compiler while all C compilers tend to share the same library) rather than just commenting on a tangential point (i.e. that technically the C library isn't part of the OS either).

Comment: Actually, there is an effort pushed by Herb Sutter (from Microsoft) to get a stable ABI for C++ with a model similar to C, see [n4028: Defining a portable C++ ABI](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/05/n4028).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Unfortunately, the state of that proposal is really just an (incomplete) set of proposed requirements and nothing concrete.  The problem is there are a lot of pitfalls around inheritance and virtual function definitions and maintaining backwards compatiblity with no go good way of addressing them

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Yes, still I have hope that there is some time before C++17 :)

Comment: Damn, your answer was on review of `Firsts Posts` and I just wanted to ask if you were talking about API instead of ABI. I failed because I clicked on comment...  I feel I have been cheated :-)

Comment: Hey guys is ABI, abstract binary interface?

Answer (score 10):

Operating systems in general do not support languages.  They only support for their own system calls.  In most operating systems this support is provided as part of the C library because C has the lowest level linkage.  Other languages and runtimes (such as C++, python, etc) build their runtime support on top of the OS's system call support library.

Comment: UNIX and C were developed together by the same group of people, so UNIX and thus POSIX systems support C and C is tightly woven into the OS in many ways.

Answer (score 9):

The C library is also maintained separately: both glibc and Windows's msvcr* (don't know the details on Mac). The fact that is "comes with the OS" is that all (most of) the binaries are linked against it, so nothing would work without it. Granted, same could be said of the C++ standard library, but not quite so strict.

The compiler often provides extensions which library writers use to facilitate development. When a new feature is implemented, the library is adapted. Sometimes these changes are breaking. In the case of glibc/libstdc++(/libc++?), backwards compatibility is maintained inside the library (using versioned symbols). In the case of Windows' CRT, various incompatible versions appeared of both the C and C++ standard libraries, coupled to each compiler version. Also: in the case of Visual Studio, the compiler tends to break ABI between versions, so "the OS" would have to come with all versions of the libraries.

PS: granted, for Windows, it might have been "cleaner" to include newer CRT/C++lib versions in Windows Update. Other choices were made way back when, and most stuck until now.

Comment: Unfortunately, some applications access the internals of the Visual Studio C runtime, which is the application's fault definitely, but it's understandable that the Visual Studio team doesn't want to break those applications.

Answer (score 2):

The source code of the C++ library is bundled with the GCC sources. This makes sense, because the C++ library goes hand in hand with the C++ language. It is not an operating system component. Certain aspects of it, like memory management and I/O, do interface with OS facilities, but much of it doesn't.

On the other hand, the actual bundling of the C++ library is the job of the operating system **distro** (for instance some flavor of GNU/Linux).

Ultimately, it is your distribution which decides how libstdc++ is packaged. For instance, it might make sense for it to be a standalone package (which might even need to appear in several versions). This is because libstdc++ provides a shared library, and that shared library is needed as a dependency by other packages, whether or not a compiler is installed. And some packages might only work with a specific version of this library.

"Part of the OS" or "part of the compiler" don't really make sense: the question is "part of what package", and that is distro-specific, because when you build the GCC suite, your build scripts can then pick apart the temporary install tree into arbitrary packages based on your vision of how to organize a distro.

> Suppose we made a "ceeplusplusy" OS distro. Then the C++ library could be considered and essential component of the OS.  That is, suppose the core applications that are needed just to bring up the OS are all rewritten in C++ and all use the library: things like a system daemon, shell, "getty" and so on. Then the C++ library is needed in early boot stages.  Ultimately, what is OS and what isn't?

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you will find both libc.dylib (Standard C library) and libc++.dylib (Standard C++ library) in the /usr/lib directory. On an iOS device, you won't find them (easily), but they are both there as well. Quite clearly, they are *not* part of the compiler, because they are essential for practically all programs to run, and they are present even if you never installed any compilers.